# Draw in the complex plane the following subgroups

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

- A1 = {Z∈C : |Z+ 3| < 2}
- A2 = {Z∈C : |Re z| + |Im z| < 1}
- A3 = {Z∈C : |Z| - z = i}
- A4 ={z∈C : |z|≤ Re z +2}

I have to calculate them? Can some one send me a documentation website where I can see how to resolve it or a little example for each one?

Regards, devteat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - A1 = {Z∈C : |z+ 3| < 2}
> - A2 = {Z∈C : |Re z| + |Im z| < 1}
> - A3 = {Z∈C : |z| - z = i}
> - A4 ={z∈C : |z|≤ Re z +2}

For each one let $z=x+iy$ which implies $\Re(z)=x$ and $\Im(z)=y$ , I also assume you know modulus.

I will do the first  for you!

> $A1$

$$|z+3| < 2$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow |x+iy+3| < 2$$

$$\Leftrightarrow |(x+3)i(y)| < 2$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{(x+3)^2+y^2 } < 2$$

$$ \therefore (x+3)^2+y^2 < 4$$

which is a circle of centre $(-3,0i)$ and radius $2$ but you need to shade in only the inside of the circle as such: [image]

I think you can do the rest now :)

Comment: A1, A2 .. have some meaning? '< 2' is the radius? Do you know any website where I can find examples and documentation to understand this right? Thanks for the example!